# How do I use ConditionalAttribute in C++-CLI?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, managed

I have a C++-CLI ref class that exposes a profiling infrastructure implemented in C++.

In C++ I have the preprocessor directive `PROFILING_ENABLED` to determine whether the intrusive profiling functions are in the code or not.

When exposing these to managed code, I thought that using the managed `ConditionalAttribute` would be appropriate. But I struggle with the syntax.

Here is my attempt:

```
#ifdef PROFILING_ENABLED

// c++ macros are defined and active on the project level, I would like the 
// conditional attribute to be active as well.

#define MANAGED_PROFILING_ENABLED

// how do I define the managed conditional "MANAGED_PROFILING_ENABLED" in C++-CLI?



#endif

    public ref class Profiler
    {
    public:
        [ConditionalAttribute("MANAGED_PROFILING_ENABLED")] // this compile but always inactive
        static void PushRange(System::String ^ name, Color color);

        [ConditionalAttribute("MANAGED_PROFILING_ENABLED")]
        static void PopRange();
    };
```

I would like to achieve the following: 
If the native c++ preprocessor directive is **active**, the managed ConditionalAttribute should be **active** as well.
If on the other hand the native c++ preprocessor directive is **inactive**, the managed ConditionalAttribute should be **inactive**.

Comment: I'll further clarify. Everything compiles, and the C++ preprocessor directive is active for sure. only the manage conditional attribute is always false. I would like it to be active or not according to the c++ preprocessor directive.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I did some edits, hope this makes the intention clearer.

Comment: The C++/CLI compiler does not have the plumbing to do the [Conditional] thing, you are expected to do this the C++ way.  Use #ifdef.

Comment: @HansPassant the [Conditional] thing does have an effect when I use it on C++/CLI. It is only the string conditional parameter that is missing. 
Anyway I use #ifdef for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below standards document is pretty old. But assume that, may be still valid.

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf

Go to section 29.4.3 (You can find below content about conditional attributes in c++/CLI).

> C++/CLI does not provide this ability; although attributes of this
>   type are accepted, they have no affect on code generation or
>   execution.